# How to load the child component under the parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

In react I am using `tsx` file. where how to load the child component under the parent component?

here is my products page:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Link,
  Route,
  Switch,
  useRouteMatch,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./products.scss";

const Shoes = React.lazy(() => import("./shoes/shoes.component"));
const Cloths = React.lazy(() => import("./cloths/cloths.component"));

export default class Products extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <header>
          <Link to="/shoe">Shoes</Link>
          <Link to="/cloths">Cloths</Link>
        </header>
        <h1>Products page</h1>;
        <main>
          <h2>Subpage goes here </h2>
          <p>sub pages should load here </p>
        </main>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

on click of the child `Link`, i looking to load them in to `main` element.

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ipxtlu?file=products/product.component.tsx)

Comment: you can load the child component inside "main" based on location condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for more information

```
   <div>
      <header>
        <Link to="/products/shoe">Shoes</Link>
        <Link to="/products/cloths">Cloths</Link>
      </header>
      <h1>Products page</h1>
      <Route path={`/products/shoe`}>
        <Shoes />
      </Route>
      <Route path={`/products/cloths`}>
        <Cloths />
      </Route>
    </div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mcgujv?file=products/product.component.tsx)

Comment: by the way I am getting an error as `Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ name: any; }'.` in `index.tsx` file. any idea? How to load the shoes as default?

Comment: make it <Home name={"dummyName"}/> inside index.tsx

Comment: shoes and cloths are loading as absolute path instead referring parent. it's not `/products/shoes` instead lading as `/shoes`.. as absolute path. how to fix it

Comment: @user2024080 hey ,something wrong with this implementation, i am working on it..will update soon.

Comment: @user2024080 please check [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mcgujv?file=products/product.component.tsx)

Comment: @user2024080 you have created 2 components-shoes and clothes.. tomorrow if you need another product say phones.. then you will be creating another static component. there is better solution.. you can have one component which will render products details based on product selection. i will soon update code.

Comment: sure thanks. as well why router is not extending from it's parent, why do we need to add the whole long path as `/products/shoe` in angular it will automatically takes the parent path and loads child from it.

Comment: fwiw look at this example for react-router nesting https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Comment: yup here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter?file=components/Topics.js)

Comment: Nilesh, how we handle this in class based component? as well I am not finding the component imported from out side

Comment: unfortunately i did not find any example for class component with react router v5. I will check and let you know.

Comment: as a simple, how do you load `About` component with your demo? I am not find a way

Comment: Loading root component is not an issue. right?. `About` is root component.

Comment: I think, `withRouter` we can use for class component. need to do some research

Comment: for static component, its easy. [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mcgujv?file=products%2Fproduct.component.tsx). for dynamic, need to do some research

Comment: yes, you are correct. need to find a way to dynamic routing approach.

Comment: take a look at this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-zunyof?file=components%2FTopics.js) with dynamic routing with class component